# Getting device by specified iccid in cumulocity?

Tags: filter, fragment, cumulocity

I  have devices in Cumulocity with "Mobile" fragment in them.
I  would like to retrieve information about a device by specifying a iccid, which is part of the "Mobile" fragment. 
For now I perform search in inventory based on filter:
InventoryFilter inventoryFilter = new InventoryFilter().byFragmentType(Mobile.class);

and then check whether the iccid in the found devices match the required.
But I would like somehow to specify iccid in the search.

Is this possible and if yes - how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You need to define a custom query similar to the query you would use via normal API call:

`...?query=$filter=c8y_Mobile.iccid eq '<<your-iccid>>'`

In Java you can have a custom filter class for this:

```
public class CustomInventoryFilter extends InventoryFilter {

@ParamSource
private String query;

public CustomInventoryFilter byQuery(final String query) {
    this.query = query;
    return this;
}
```

Instead of the InventoryFilter.class you use this custom class and add the same query as above into `.byQuery("c8y_Mobile.iccid eq '<<your-iccid>>'"`)

Comment: Actually it worked with `.byQuery("c8y_Mobile.iccid eq '<<your-iccid>>'"'`, Thanks a lot for the hint.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I updated my answer accordingly.